# How to set active profile in application.yml of a Micronaut application?

Tags: micronaut

I've the following config files in a Micronaut application -

- application.yml
- application-dev.yml
- application-qa.yml

How to set the active profile in application.yml? In Spring Boot this can be done by adding the property **spring.profiles.active: "dev"** in application.yml.

What is the equivalent of **spring.profiles.active** in Micronaut?

Comment: Why is that you want to use the `application.yml` bundled in the app to define the apps profile?  The answer to that will affect the best way to satisfy that goal.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Incase of running the application from IDE, it is convenient to have that config in application.yml, so that i don't have to change the Run configuration of the application in IDE which i find less convenient to do so. Btw, is there a way to specify this config in application.yml?

Comment: "Incase of running the application from IDE, it is convenient to have that config in application.yml" - This question asks about setting the profile in `application.yml` but there are better ways to accomplish what you are talking about.  If you post a question asking how to satisfy your actual requirement, a separate set of answers to that will likely be more helpful.  I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

we can use the environment which is available

```
java -Dmicronaut.environments=dev -jar myapp.jar
```

Please check this documentation
https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#environments

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Btw, is there a way to specify this config in application.yml?

Answer (score 0):

> How to set the active profile in application.yml?

I don't think that is supported.

> What is the equivalent of spring.profiles.active in Micronaut?

There isn't an exact equivalent.  Probably the closest thing that we support is `micronaut.environments`.